# Как разбить сложную строку на массив сохраняя имена значений

Tags: javascript

Имеется строка:

```
name: "a.1=Name1, b=Name2, c.11=Name3"
```

Подскажите как разбить сроку `name` на массив, пример:

```
name: [
a.1: Name1,
b: Name2,
c.11: Name3
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только это не массив, а объект

```js
let name = "a.1=Name1, b=Name2, c.11=Name3"

console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(
    name.split(/[,\s]+/).map((v) => v.split('='))
  )
)
```

Дополнение для коммента: почти как и выше.

Если точно известно, что запятая используется только в разделении свойств - используем ее как обязательный делитель и добавляем после нее любое кол-во пробельных необязательных - это при split-е сразу вырежет лишние пробелы и не установит их перед именами свойств.

```
/,\s*/
",  foo" => [, "foo"]
/,/ - без \s 
",  foo" => [, "  foo"]
```

```js
let name = 'SN=Фамилия, G=Имя Отчество, CN="ООО "РИК"", T=Генеральный директор, O="ООО "РИК"", OU=0, STREET=ул. Улица д. 7, L=г. Город, S=50 Московская область, C=RU, ИНН=001633399240, ОГРН=5083155076736, СНИЛС=44667182819, E=test@test.ru';

console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(
    name.split(/,\s*/).map((v) => v.split('='))
  )
)
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу разбить данную строку, ваше решение не помогло. ```var name = 'SN=Фамилия, G=Имя Отчество, CN="ООО "РИК"", T=Генеральный директор, O="ООО "РИК"", OU=0, STREET=ул. Улица д. 7, L=г. Город, S=50 Московская область, C=RU, ИНН=001633399240, ОГРН=5083155076736, СНИЛС=44667182819, E=test@test.ru';
```

Comment: @j.ss обновил, почти так же

Comment: @j.ss, не забудьте принять ответ, если он вас удовлетворил.